# document.getElementbyId() returning null

Tags: javascript, dom

In the code at the line marked as //Error in comments. I get Javascript error saying: "Cannot read property style of 'null'". I have no idea what it is not able to find the object. I have thought and tried everything. Please help. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/647045111?fields=first_name&<%= Session["Token"] %>',

    function (data) {
        $('#userName').html(data.first_name);
    });

    document.getElementById('connectedUnregistered').style.display = 'block'; //Error

</script>

    <div id="userName"></div>

    <div id="disconnected" style="display:block;">

     <div id="heading">Facebook login</div> 

     <a href="Account/FacebookLogin" id="loginButton"><div id="fbConnectButton"><img src="/Content/Images/fbconnect.png"/></div></a>    

    </div>

     <div id="connectedUnregistered" style="display:none">

     <div id="heading">Register Now</div> 



    </div>
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You are executing your javascript code BEFORE the `<div id="connectedUnregistered" />` was actually created.

Also note that you did not close your `<div>` with a corresponding `</div>`.

So move your javascript code to a part below your HTML. Or execute it after the page finished loading. If you are using JQuery you can do:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        ... your code ...

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Put your script at the end of the HTML document instead of the beginning, and see if that solves things.

JavaScript can't edit the DOM element because it hasn't been created yet.

Comment: this is the acceptable answer for websites that can help their surfers use modern browsers. People targeting the open internet, with all kinds of browsers, must use the $(document).ready malarkey

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps try placing this code in a

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//Code

});
```

block

Answer (score 2):

in my case it was because of having this line at the beginning of the jsp/html(whatever) file:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

removing it solved the problem for me(I do not remember what it was doing on my page at first place)

Answer (score 1):

Also, if in some part of the code you are using `document.write` it's very common to get null.

Answer (score 0):

The script is trying to get the element before the element is loaded. Place the script after the element or put it in a load or ready event.

Answer (score 0):

The code executes prior to the element being created.   Since you are using jquery, simply wrap it in document.ready:

```
$(function(){
    // code goes here
});
```

This will execute after the DOM is created.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript code is running before the DOM is fully available and the call fails.  Try the following instead

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById('connectedUnregistered').style.display = 'block'; //Error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error could also indicate that the element doesn't have an ID.

```
<input type="text" name="myelem" />
```

Make sure your element has an ID.

```
<input type="text" name="myelem" id="myelem" />
```