# Body.onLoad seems to execute too early

Tags: javascript, html

**EDIT : SORRY, PROBLEM IS DIFFERENT** 
- It should be `<textarea id="txtScene">` 
  instead of `<textarea name="txtScene">`

---

It seems that `<body onLoad="init();">` executes `init();` before all HTML contend inside `body` is created.

I particular, have this HTML:

```
<script src="/home/prokop/Dropbox/MyDevSW/javascript/WebGL/shader_builder/GLSLscreen.js"></script>
<body onLoad="init_GLSLScreen();">
    <textarea name="txtScene" cols="60" rows="20" onChange="updateShader(this)">
        vec4 scene( Ray ray ){
            vec4 hit = vec4( POSITIVE_INF, vec3(0.0) );
            Sphere SURF1 = Sphere( vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0), 1.0 );
            Sphere SURF2 = Sphere( vec3(1.0,0.0,0.0), 0.75 );
            Sphere SURF3 = Sphere( vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0), 0.75 );
            vec2 ts1;
            ADD( SURF1 );
            SUB( SURF2 );
            SUB( SURF3 );
            return hit;
        } 
    </textarea>
</body>
```

and inside `init_GLSLScreen()` I need to run `updateShader` with `textarea name="txtScene"` as an argument. Like this

```
function init_GLSLScreen(){
    // ... some stuff ... don't care
    console.log ( document.getElementById("txtScene") );
    updateShader( document.getElementById("txtScene") );
    // ... some stuff ... don't care
}
```

But `document.getElementById("txtScene")` returns `null`

The problem is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151904/document-getelementbyid-returning-null) with solution to either move the javascript below HTML (I guess not possible in my case) or to run the javascript `onLoad` ... which I do but does not work.

---

Striped down code which reproduces this behaviour (if you look into web-console)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>05.10 - Custom fragment shader</title>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
    </style>
</head>
<script>
     function init_GLSLScreen(){
        console.log ( document.getElementById("txtScene") );
        console.log ( document.getElementById("txtScene").value );
    }
</script>
    <body>
        <textarea name="txtScene" cols="60" rows="20" onChange="updateShader(this)">
            sfsdjfskldjflj
        </textarea>
    </body>
    <script>
     init_GLSLScreen();
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute Javascript When Page Has Fully Loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033398/execute-javascript-when-page-has-fully-loaded)

Comment: I use `window.onload` but does work (still some elements are not initialized)

Comment: Am I blind or is there no `id="txtScene"` in the textarea? You want to select an element by id, so you have to add it `<textarea id="txtScene" ...`

Comment: Andrele > Yes, I just  realized that. I was thinking `name` is the same thing as `id` ... I have no experience with javascript

Answer (score 1):

You could always move your function execution to the bottom of the html, just before the closing body tag. This will ensure that everything is loaded in the DOM.

```
<script>
   init_GLSLScreen();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can include jquery then it's a matter of wrapping your code in `$(document).ready(function() {});` see: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

if you can't /don't want to include jquery then I would get the javascript that makes up the source of the .ready function in jquery that way you can duplicate the same functionality.

See here for a plan: [$(document).ready() source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430455/document-ready-source)

If you wanted to use jquery you can just do this:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"
  integrity="sha256-Qw82+bXyGq6MydymqBxNPYTaUXXq7c8v3CwiYwLLNXU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="/home/prokop/Dropbox/MyDevSW/javascript/WebGL/shader_builder/GLSLscreen.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        init_GLSLScreen();
     });
</script>
<body >
    <textarea name="txtScene" cols="60" rows="20" onChange="updateShader(this)">
        vec4 scene( Ray ray ){
            vec4 hit = vec4( POSITIVE_INF, vec3(0.0) );
            Sphere SURF1 = Sphere( vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0), 1.0 );
            Sphere SURF2 = Sphere( vec3(1.0,0.0,0.0), 0.75 );
            Sphere SURF3 = Sphere( vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0), 0.75 );
            vec2 ts1;
            ADD( SURF1 );
            SUB( SURF2 );
            SUB( SURF3 );
            return hit;
        } 
    </textarea>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks ... I don't know what `jquery` is.  I'm not web programer ... I just use javascript as a simple way how to present my GLSL shaders on github.

Comment: I tried, but still I get `null` ... perhaps there is different problem ... but I don't see what. I use `three.js` if that matters somehow